# Can I use Spring boot to enable my Selenium Web Driver to run?

Tags: spring-boot, selenium

I am currently developing crawling for websites that require login functions.

I think the site is not just a site where you can log in when you import cookies and insert them, but rather a part where you have to let users enter their IDs and passwords.

The structure of my spring boot is as follows.

1. input tag for entering accessible URLs after login
2. Login Button

At this point, when you press the login button, the Web Driver opens on the user's side, receives the user's input, processes the login, and then attempts to create a service that crawls URL 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot is a server-side framework (for back-end development). You can start WebDriver within your logic but certainly not on a client side. If you could easily start processes on a client side that would be a great security whole.

What you can do is to generate Selenium script and return it with the instructions how to run that script with a WebDriver.

P.S. - It is also worth looking into browser addons development articles that would probably make the user experience better.

Comment: Thank you. After considering this and that, I think we will develop a Chrome extension program.